# ItemsControl modify Items at runtime

Tags: wpf, silverlight, xaml

in my Silverlight project I have the following ItemsControl :

```
<ItemsControl x:Name="ItemsList">
    <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
    <ItemsPanelTemplate>
        <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" />
    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>

    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>

        <Border x:Name="brdItem" Opacity="1" MouseLeftButtonDown="brdItem_MouseLeftButtonDown">
            <TextBlock x:Name="txtUsername" Text="{Binding Username}" />
        </Border>

    </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>

</ItemsControl>
```

What I want is :
When my user clicks on an item.  I want all the other items Opacity set to "0.3". 
When the mouse is released I want all the items to come back to their original state (Opacity="1").

Comment: You could try creating a `MultiTrigger` on `Mouse.IsLeftButtonDown = True` and `ItemsControl.IsMouseOver = True` and `txtUserName.IsMouseOver = False`. Those are probably not the actual property names, but it should give you the an idea

Answer (score 2):

It's very simple if to use the MVVM pattern. Add the `Opacity` property to the item class and bind it to the `Border.Opacity` property:

```
<Border x:Name="brdItem" Opacity="{Binding Opacity}" MouseLeftButtonDown="brdItem_MouseLeftButtonDown">
    <TextBlock x:Name="txtUsername" Text="{Binding Username}" />
</Border>
```

The item class:

```
public class ItemViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public string Username { get; set; }

    private double _opacity;

    public double Opacity
    {
        get { return _opacity; }
        set
        {
            _opacity = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged("Opacity");
        }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected virtual void RaisePropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        if (this.PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            this.PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
}
```

After that your mouse event will look so:

```
    public void brdItem_MouseLeftButtonDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        var vm = ((FrameworkElement)sender).DataContext as ItemViewModel;
        if (vm != null)
        {
            vm.Opacity = 1;
            this.ItemsList.ItemsSource.OfType<ItemViewModel>()
                .Where(item => item != vm)
                .ToList()
                .ForEach(item => item.Opacity = 0.3);
        }
    }
```

To return back to the initial state use the following code:

```
this.ItemsList.ItemsSource.OfType<ItemViewModel>()
    .ToList().ForEach(item => item.Opacity = 1);
```

Comment: Great suggestion, but I don't want to add "Opacity" property to my object.  (Actually the ItemsSource is in public property a UserControl and its an IEnumerable so it can receive any type of objects)

Comment: @danbord That's what ViewModel about: to create a wrapper to which you can add any properties that you want without changing source objects. It's like an adapter or converter. As to the ItemsSource property, at first I thought to use an extra MainViewModel class which contains items, but then I decided to reduce amount of code in the answer in order to make it simplier.